# Make a UIView receive taps but pass swipes to the underlying view

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, swift2

I've got a `UITableView` and a big "button" view in front of it. The "button" view, which has transparent areas, should be able to response to a tap. But enabling user interaction for this view blocks any scrolling touches from getting to the table view located under the "button" view.

The upper view is a `UIView` (not `UIButton`). Given how the two views work together, the upper view is essentially part of what's going on with the table view and reacts to the table view being scrolled. But scrolling is the main thing and I'd like the user to have the largest scrolling area possible.

How do I best resolve this conflict so that the table view is scrollable as usual?

Comment: Why do you want scrolling on the `TableView` when something is partially covering anyways? This seems like bad interface design if you ask me. There's a reason Apple made this the default behavior for situations like that.

Comment: The upper view is quite big and would leave an insufficiently small scrolling area if not made transient for user scrolling touches. That view really needs to be in there, above the table view.

Comment: But my point is, if you have a large ("quite big...insufficiently small scrolling area") view blocking your table view, then why would the user need to be able to scroll the tableview to begin with?

Comment: The table view is not visually blocked. It can be seen through the upper view. I pointed it out in the question. The two views are connected logically and interactively.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could subclass your UIButton and UITableView common superview, and override its `hitTest:withEvent:` to verify which view is hit, something like if you are in a clear or an opaque part of the button?

As pbush25 is mentionning however, it goes more or less against Apple's recommendation.

Comment: The upper view is a UIView, not UIButton. Given how the two views work together, the upper view is essentially part of what's going on with the table view and responds to the table view being scrolled. But scrolling is the main thing and I'd like the user to have the largest scrolling area possible.

Comment: What i get from your question is that there is a UIView A, with a UITableView B and a UIButton C as subviews.
I was talking about subclassing that A superview, to choose between subviews in hitTest.

Comment: No UIButton's, just two UIView's. The upper view works analogous to a button though.

Comment: How would `hitTest` know whether it's a tap or scrolling that needs to be performed?

Comment: Oh ok. I still think my answer applies, though ^^. Override the superview hitTest:, use it to check which subview is selected, and call this subview HitTest:.

Comment: Depends on your criteria for deciding what part of your "button" view is hitable (I guess i'd go for something with a layer mask?). The hitTest: just returns to the system which view will handle the tap.

Comment: All  the area of the upper view is hitable. So I don't see how hitTest could possibly help here. It's taps and swipes that need to be segregated. The app tries to go big on visuals.

Comment: I would really not do this kind of UX, though.

Comment: Thanks for your attention anyways

Comment: For info, the hitTest: is what is called before the swapping and tapping intervenes. I'm pretty sure your solution would imply making the "button" view hitTest return nil when a swap is detected. As for switching it back on, i don't know. If your need is "simply" to detect taps, you could use the TableView cells for that (aka If they are tapped, the "button" was tapped).